# Title with image is not coming while exporting chart?

Tags: highcharts

I want to export chart with title image,but when i tried to export the chart image is missing from chart,please suggest,Is any way to export chart with title Image.

`My Implemented code`:[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sameekmishra/LHSey/188/)

Thanks

Comment: It is recommended that you do put your code in your question. What happens if jsFiddle is not available for some reason?

Comment: Hi, This is small highcharts issue, you can find information about it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4651 I think that as a workaround you can use renderer.image() method. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image Here you can find really simple example showing that this method may work in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/LHSey/190/

Comment: @Grzegorx : Thanks.